# Cannot open UDP ports for docker containers in GNS3 for inter-container port access

Tags: docker, networking, udp, dockerfile, docker-container

I have a gns3 ubuntu 16.04 machine appliance that I installed from GNS3 market place. I am trying to simulate DDoS amplification attack in GNS3 (version 2.1.21). Part of it, I want to open UDP ports vulnerable to amplification (such as NTP : 123, DNS : 53, CHARGEN : 19....).

I tried to use `iptables` command to switch open the ports, but this is not available on ubuntu containers in GNS3. I then tried to create my own docker image with ubuntu 16.04 and use `EXPOSE 123/udp` in the DockerFile. I build the docker image and import in GNS3. Still all ports on container remains closed.

Nmap scan on the container gives me `All 1000 scanned ports are closed`. How do I open udp ports on my ubuntu containers so I can send udp traffic from one container to other ?

[image: GNS3 with ubuntu 16.04 docker container]

Comment: you need to add `-p 123:123/udp` to your docker run command

Comment: But in GNS3 you don't directly run docker containers. But you can make DockerFile and build your own base images and run within GNS3. If you can direct me how to do it in GNS3 that'd be very helpful. I've found lot of support for how to do it in docker but not in GNS3.

Comment: sorry I have no idea how to do this in GNS3